Conteo Total peso de Archivos php
espero que bien me puedan ayudar con esto.. tengo este código que me lista los archivos y en ellos hago acciones (eliminar, Editar etc...) y al lado de estos se muestra el peso del archivo en si. usando filesize en eso no tengo problema.. pues me lista los archivos y al lado el peso de los mismos... esta información del peso de cada archivo en el bucle la guardo en la variable $filesizeecho luego mediante una función le hago la conversión si esta esta en bytes o MB etc. y la muestro pero
¿Como hago para mostrar el numero de archivos en el Bucle y como hago para que la variable $filesizeecho guarde en cada iteración del bucle la suma de cada $filesizeecho y la muestre el total al final del listado?
Numero de archivos:  #    Peso Total: #
   while ($rowp=mysql_fetch_array($resultp))
    {
$archi="archivos/".$rowp["archivo_docu"];
$filesizeecho = filesize($archi);



$inicial = strtoupper(substr($rowp['descripcion_docu'], 0, 1));
if($rowp['numero']==""){
$nummj=" ";
    }else{
$nummj=" N. ";
    }
if($rowp['contador_docu']==""){
$rayitt=" ";
}else{
$rayitt="-";
}
// FUNCION CONVERTIR bytes a KB - MB ----------------------------
function size_as_kb($size) {
if($size < 1024) {
return "{$size} bytes";
} elseif($size < 1048576) {
$size_kb = round($size/1024);
return "{$size_kb} KB";
} else {
$size_mb = round(size/1048576, 1);
return "{$size_mb} MB";
}
}
echo "<a style='color: #FF0000;' rel='pop-up2confirm' href=\"elimina.php?id=$rowp[id_doc]&archivo=$rowp[archivo_docu]&idper=$id_permisosdecode\" title='Eliminar' > X </a>";
echo " - ";
echo "<a style='color: #000000;' rel='pop-up2edit' href=\"editar.php?id=$rowp[id_doc]&archivo=$rowp[archivo_docu]&idper=$id_permisosdecode\" title='Editar'>&#9998;</a>";
echo " - ";
echo "<a rel='pop-up2' href=\"archivos/$rowp[archivo_docu]\" target=\"_blank\">".strtoupper($rowp['descripcion_docu']).$nummj.$rowp['numero_docu']." COD: ".$rowp['codigo_docu'].$rayitt.$rowp['contador_docu']."</a>";
echo " - ";
echo "Peso : ".size_as_kb($filesizeecho);
echo "<br>";
         }


si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

Hay varias cosas a tomar en cuenta:

Inicializar un contador para el número de archivos.
Inicializar una variable para acumular el tamaño total de los archivos.
Incrementar el contador y sumar el tamaño de cada archivo dentro del bucle.
Mostrar los resultados al final del bucle.

codigo:

// Supongo que ya tienes $resultp como el resultado de tu consulta SQL
$total_files = 0;
$total_size = 0;

while ($rowp = mysql_fetch_array($resultp)) {
    $archi = "archivos/" . $rowp["archivo_docu"];
    $filesize = filesize($archi);
    $filesizeecho = size_as_kb($filesize);

    // Incrementar contador de archivos
    $total_files++;
    // Acumular tamaño total
    $total_size += $filesize;

    $inicial = strtoupper(substr($rowp['descripcion_docu'], 0, 1));
    $nummj = ($rowp['numero'] == "") ? " " : " N. ";
    $rayitt = ($rowp['contador_docu'] == "") ? " " : "-";

    // Mostrar información del archivo
    echo "<a style='color: #FF0000;' rel='pop-up2confirm' href=\"elimina.php?id={$rowp['id_doc']}&archivo={$rowp['archivo_docu']}&idper=$id_permisosdecode\" title='Eliminar'> X </a>";
    echo " - ";
    echo "<a style='color: #000000;' rel='pop-up2edit' href=\"editar.php?id={$rowp['id_doc']}&archivo={$rowp['archivo_docu']}&idper=$id_permisosdecode\" title='Editar'>&#9998;</a>";
    echo " - ";
    echo "<a rel='pop-up2' href=\"archivos/{$rowp['archivo_docu']}\" target=\"_blank\">" . strtoupper($rowp['descripcion_docu']) . $nummj . $rowp['numero_docu'] . " COD: " . $rowp['codigo_docu'] . $rayitt . $rowp['contador_docu'] . "</a>";
    echo " - ";
    echo "Peso: " . $filesizeecho;
    echo "<br>";
}

// Mostrar número de archivos y peso total
echo "Numero de archivos: $total_files<br>";
echo "Peso Total: " . size_as_kb($total_size);

// Función para convertir tamaño a KB, MB, etc.
function size_as_kb($size) {
    if ($size < 1024) {
        return "{$size} bytes";
    } elseif ($size < 1048576) {
        $size_kb = round($size / 1024);
        return "{$size_kb} KB";
    } else {
        $size_mb = round($size / 1048576, 1);
        return "{$size_mb} MB";
    }
}

otra forma un tanto compleja pero que a la vez permite implementar POO y hacer scalable este script seria mediante el uso de clases y metodos, tratando los datos como objetos:
class FileProcessor {
    private $result;
    private $totalFiles;
    private $totalSize;

    public function __construct($result) {
        $this->result = $result;
        $this->totalFiles = 0;
        $this->totalSize = 0;
    }

    public function processFiles() {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($this->result)) {
            $this->processFile($row);
        }
        $this->displaySummary();
    }

    private function processFile($row) {
        $filePath = "archivos/" . $row["archivo_docu"];
        $fileSize = filesize($filePath);

        // Incrementar contador de archivos y acumular tamaño total
        $this->totalFiles++;
        $this->totalSize += $fileSize;

        // Preparar detalles del archivo
        $description = strtoupper($row['descripcion_docu']);
        $number = !empty($row['numero_docu']) ? " N. " . $row['numero_docu'] : "";
        $counter = !empty($row['contador_docu']) ? "-" . $row['contador_docu'] : "";

        // Mostrar información del archivo
        echo $this->generateFileHTML($row, $description, $number, $counter, $fileSize);
    }

    private function generateFileHTML($row, $description, $number, $counter, $fileSize) {
        $fileLinks = "<a style='color: #FF0000;' rel='pop-up2confirm' href=\"elimina.php?id={$row['id_doc']}&archivo={$row['archivo_docu']}&idper={$id_permisosdecode}\" title='Eliminar'> X </a>";
        $fileLinks .= " - ";
        $fileLinks .= "<a style='color: #000000;' rel='pop-up2edit' href=\"editar.php?id={$row['id_doc']}&archivo={$row['archivo_docu']}&idper={$id_permisosdecode}\" title='Editar'>&#9998;</a>";
        $fileLinks .= " - ";
        $fileLinks .= "<a rel='pop-up2' href=\"archivos/{$row['archivo_docu']}\" target=\"_blank\">{$description}{$number} COD: {$row['codigo_docu']}{$counter}</a>";
        $fileLinks .= " - ";
        $fileLinks .= "Peso: " . $this->formatSize($fileSize);
        $fileLinks .= "<br>";

        return $fileLinks;
    }

    private function formatSize($size) {
        if ($size < 1024) {
            return "{$size} bytes";
        } elseif ($size < 1048576) {
            return round($size / 1024) . " KB";
        } else {
            return round($size / 1048576, 1) . " MB";
        }
    }

    private function displaySummary() {
        echo "Numero de archivos: {$this->totalFiles}<br>";
        echo "Peso Total: " . $this->formatSize($this->totalSize);
    }
}

// Supongamos que $resultp es el resultado de la consulta SQL
$resultp = ... ; // Aquí deberías tener tu consulta SQL

$fileProcessor = new FileProcessor($resultp);
$fileProcessor->processFiles();

No he tenido tiempo de probarlo, asique pueden haver errores.
